# Jquery how to pass value id from one event handler to another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I have an `add-row` button. On its click I am adding a row into my `datatable`.

```
$('.add-row').on('click', function() {
            id = 0;
            name = $('#name').val();
            email = $('#email').val();
            cno = $('#cno').val();
            bdy = $('#bday').val();
            
            t.row.add([
                name,
                email,
                cno,
                bdy,
                '<button class ="btn btn-danger del">Delete</button>' + '' + '<button class="btn btn-warning upd" data-id="'+$('#example').DataTable().rows().count()+'">Edit</button>'





            ]).draw(false);
            $("#name").val('');
            $("#email").val('');
            $("#cno").val('');
            $("#bday").val('');

        });
```

In the above code, I am using `data-id` and adding `row id` to it. On my `edit` button click I am getting the `data-id` value.

```
$("body").on("click", ".upd", function(e) {
            const id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            console.log(id);
            // Prevent event propagation
            e.stopPropagation();
            var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var data = t.row($row).data();

            //alert('Edit ' + data[0]);
             name = data[0];
             email = data[1];
             cno = data[2];
             bdy = data[3];

            console.log(name);
            console.log(email);
            console.log(cno);
            console.log(bdy);

            $("#name1").val(name);
            $("#email1").val(email);
            $("#cno1").val(cno);
            $("#dob1").val(bdy);
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            

        });
```

The above code takes input data from `modal`. In my `modal` I have a `save` button having id `btnsubmit`. Now on this button click, I want to pass my `data-id`.

```
$("#btnsubmit").on('click',function () {//in this event i want to pass the `data-id`
             
            
            var new_name = $("#name1").val();
                var new_email = $("#email1").val();
                var new_cno = $("#cno1").val();
                var new_dob = $("#dob1").val();
              
            
           
       
                $("#myModal").modal("hide");
            });
```

How can I pass the value of `data-id` in it?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: i dont understant you want to pass value to your modal?

Comment: Yes so that I when I  click the `save` button I should have the `data-id` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could stock your data in html modal like this:

```
$("#myModal").data('id', id);
```

and use:

```
var id = $("#myModal").data('id');
```